# Create videos programmatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, imovie

Is there a way to create videos programmatically in Rails?

**Are any of these two options possible:**

1. Create a movie based on supplied images and soundtrack?
2. Modify an iMovie project in Ruby/Rails somehow? If I have a project already created with transitions, etc. Is there a way I can put in images in placeholder places in the movie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're looking for will be built in Ruby, and probably not use any of Rails.

The only way that I know how to do this is to create a SWF using [Ming](http://mingruby.rubyforge.org/).

There's a pretty good example on how to use it [here](http://www.ioncannon.net/ruby/108/flash-video-steam-ming-php-ruby/)