# Creating Videos in a Ruby On Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, youtube

I'm looking for a way of taking an audio asset and jpeg from my app that are both stored on Amazon S3 and merge them into a video that's format will be accepted at Youtube. Basically, the song with static album artwork for the duration.

I've seen this post that refers to Ming-Ruby [Create videos programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502353/create-videos-programatically) but i'm wondering if the Gem is active and maintained or if anyone else has experience of doing something similar and can offer some tips or alternative approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using ffmpeg. Here's some examples of creating a video slideshow of images. http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images I'm sure you could find info out there on how to also add in audio. At that point you should just need to find a ffmpeg gem to wrap the calls you need to make or work directly with it via system calls (be careful with that though).

Comment: I've just been looking at that combined with the Rvideo Gem so think i'll do some trials. My concern is getting it all working when deployed to Heroku. Thanks for your answer.